# how to find date in arraylist and display messgae from database

Tags: android

im getting dates from database see database:

[image]

im loding dates in array list  i want tocheck if current date exist in arraylistthen print title of that day how i will do that?

```
                static ArrayList<String> Vacation_ID = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Vacation_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Vacation_Date = new ArrayList<String>();


            Cursor mCursor3 =  db.selectQuery("SELECT * FROM uss_vacation WHERE calendar_id = 
                '"+Calendar_id+"' ");


    if (mCursor3.moveToFirst()) {
        do {



    Vacation_ID.add(mCursor3.getString(mCursor3.getColumnIndex("id")));

           Vacation_name.add(mCursor3.getString(mCursor3.getColumnIndex("title")));

            Vacation_Date.add(mCursor3.getString(mCursor3.getColumnIndex("date")));


        } while (mCursor3.moveToNext());
    }


    mCursor3.close();


            now i want to check if current date exist in araylist   Vacation_Date show title  
    of   that date like  
            if (Vacation_Date.contains("2013-11-11")) {
                 string datetitle;
                    datetitle="Veterans Day" from database
```

Comment: are you storing date as String in database..?

Comment: in which date format like dd-MM-yyyy or any thing..?

Comment: then use if(currentDate.equals(dbDate)){}

Comment: I ALREADY DEFINE "2013-11-11"

Comment: i want to print "title" of that date which exist in database check my screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the date in an array list so, you will need to check every element of array list if the string containing matches the date specified by you.

Compare the ArrayList values as follows:-

```
String datetitle = "";
for (int index = 0; index< Vacation_Date.size();index++)
{
     String date = Vacation_Date.get(index);
     if(date.contains("2013-11-11"));
     //datetitle = "your value";
}
```